# CopiesList.addAll method throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

```
List<String> hi = Collections.nCopies(10, "Hi");
List<String> are = Collections.nCopies(10, "Are");

hi.addAll(are);

hi.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
  at com.practice.java8.lambdaexp.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

I think AbstractList.add() doesn't have implementation in JDK. That is why it's not working.

But if I create a new ArrayList object using a CopiesList object it works, because it will have a proper add() implementation.

My question is: Why doesn't  `CopiesList` have a proper implementation for addAll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collections.nCopies` returns an immutable `List`, so you can't add anything to it:

> Returns an **immutable** list consisting of n copies of the specified object.

It returns an immutable `List` since it only contains a single reference of the element you pass to its constructor:

> The newly allocated data object is tiny (**it contains a single reference to the data object**).

This is done for the benefit of performance and storage requirements - `Collections.nCopies(10, "Hi")` and `Collections.nCopies(10000000, "Hi")` occupy the same amount of space.

Therefore it would be very difficult to implement it as a mutable List. How would you set, for example, the `10000`'th element to some new value if there's no storage allocated for that element?

If you need a mutable List that contains copies of the same object, you have to pass the immutable List to some mutable List constructor:

```
List<String> mutable = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, "Hi"));
```

Answer (score 5):

As the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)) says, the returned list is immutable, which means you can't modify it:

> [nCopies] Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified object.

Maybe you didn't get the "in combination with the List.addAll" part. You must have a non-immutable list in which you can add all your elements:

```
List modifiableList = new ArrayList<String>();

List<String> hi = Collections.nCopies(10, "Hi");
List<String> are = Collections.nCopies(10, "Are");

modifiableList.addAll(are);
modifiableList.addAll(hi);

modifiableList.forEach(System.out::println);
```